# How can view the source code of the lambda expression in the run time(C#)?

Tags: c#, lambda

All, I am trying to figure out how does lambda expression works in the complied time also in the run time. Say you have the source code like below.
[image]

Currently, I tried to quick watch the variable. But unfortunately. Can not make it to view the source code of the `Fun` .Is there any other way to view what does actually code the `Func<int> ageCalculator` run?. Thanks.

**Updated**

No lucky things in the reflector kind tools. Please see it in the `dotPeek`. Thanks.

[image]

**Updated 1**

There are more items (Compiled generated class items) displayed in the tree when the option is enabled. But double-clicked these items. Just display the `MyTempClass` source code no new thing. What does it suppose to display ? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Read the assembly using Reflector?

Comment: You're defining ```Func<int> ageCalculator``` one line earlier than where you're calling it. So you know it'll run the ```AgeC....``` method that's hidden behind that pop-up, right?

Comment: @RickvandenBosch I suppose this is just for simplicity within this question.

Comment: The example above is just for illustration purpose. It is simple. The actually code is very complicated and is hard to debug and trace. I just tried to figure out how it works by debug and trace the `Func` code. Thanks.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes. Right.

Comment: Please tell me anything I can to do for improvement so that the question is not going to be down voted. Thanks.

Comment: Func is compiled code. Are you able to store your find as an expression<Func...

Comment: @BobVale I already tried the way you suggested.Please check the comment I left in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue is that by returning a Func you return a compiled lambda, you want to return an `Expression<Func<int>>` instead. You can then call `ToString()` to see its representation and `Compile().Invoke()` to run it

```
Expression<Func<int>> AgeCalculator() {
  int myAge = 30;
  return () => myAge;
}

public void Closure() {
  var ageCalculator = AgeCalculator();
  Console.WriteLine(ageCalculator.ToString());
  Console.WriteLine(ageCalculator.Compile().Invoke());
}
```

Comment: Got it . It sounds like a new lambda expression with generated class code display . It looks like `()=>value(xxxnamespace.xxxtestclass+()c_DisplayClass1_0.myAge)`.  What does it mean `value`? I didn't found it in the MSDN. Thanks.

Comment: I meant what does `ageCalculator.ToString()` display in the `Console`.

Comment: `value(xxxnamespace.xxxtestclass+()c_DisplayClass1_0.myAg‌​e)` returns the value of the captured context variable myAge

Comment: @Joe.wang the ToString() will return the string representation of the lambda.  If you are debugging then you can inspect the lambda

Comment: Once you have the expression instead of just a func, you could use the accepted answer to this question [convert-lambdaexpression-to-string-including-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478711/convert-lambdaexpression-to-string-including-values) to output a more useful string

Comment: helpful link. Thanks. @BobVale

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the C# source code, because there is none. There's a class generated automatically by the compiler, so the only thing you could see is intermediate code (IL). That IL code might be displayed as C# by other tools like Reflector (I don't have such a tool integrated in Visual Studio, so I can't try).

You can see it in dotPeek when you enable "Show compiler generated code":

[image: dotPeek Setting]

Next, right click and choose "Decompiled sources" to show the generated code:

[image: dotPeek Showing the generated class]

Comment: Can I view the generated class for the `Func` in the dotPeek? Thanks.

Comment: I can see the more item (generated class) shown in the tree after I enable the option. But still can not see the content the generated class code. Like `<>c_DisplayClass1_0`. Double click it . It just show me the `'MyTempClass` source code like in the my post. Thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang: exchanged screenshot and gave additional information

Comment: Ok. I just updated the original post. Please help to check it .Thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang: as written in my answer: right click and choose "Decompiled sources"

Comment: Got it . I can see it now. The `CompilerGenerated`. Thanks your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see some stuff not entirely being used as it is intended to. Please consider the code below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // You do not call the method to assign it to the variable, 
        // you point to the method (without parentheses)
        Func<int> answer = GetTheAnswerToEverything;

        // Here you actually call the method
        Console.WriteLine(answer());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // This is the method that you call when you write **add()**
    private static int GetTheAnswerToEverything() => 42;
}
```

In this example, you actually call the GetTheAnswerToEverything method when you invoke answer().

For more information, see [Func Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx)

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of the type specified by the TResult parameter.

Comment: I tried to print it in the `Closure()` like `Console.WriteLine(ageCalculator.ToString());`. But only got info like `System.Func ~1[System.Int32]` .

Comment: That's because you're not _calling_ the method. You're pointing at it. If you want to print the result, call the method ```Console.WriteLine(ageCalculator());```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this it's what you want, but [`LinqPad`](https://www.linqpad.net/) has some views `Tree`, `IL` that maybe it's what you're looking for....

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Can LinqPad view the detail of lambda (such as source code or generated class code)from the assembly dll?

Comment: BTW. Isn't it better to view the actually running source code when deduging the lambda expression.  Right?

Comment: the IL tab is the generated code.... I don't know what are you expecting to see about the lambda expression, maybe reading the sourcecode https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6dbbba50dd6655cd