# Function predicate to string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, delegates

My learning of expression is really basic, I have the following function predicate

```
Func<RecordViewModel, Func<ReportModel, bool>> exp = rec => x => x.Firstname == rec.Firstname &&
                                                                 x.Surname == rec.Surname;

var func = exp(new RecordViewModel() { Firstname= "Peter", Surname  = "Jones" });
```

The Following are my model and viewmodel,

```
public class ReportModel
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
public class RecordViewModel
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get the expression serialized to 
((ReportModel.Firstname == "Peter") AndAlso (ReportModel.Surname == "Jones")).

Any help of this is greatly appreciated,

Comment: I believe that you are trying to check for a `ReportModel` whose FirstName is "Peter" and Surname is "John" then return the result as a `RecordViewModel` right?

Comment: No, ReportModel is the argument from UI and want to log the filter criteria as string

Comment: So the return should be a string and not a boolean?

Comment: Yes, a string ,like  ((ReportModel.Firstname == "Peter") AndAlso (ReportModel.Surname == "Jones")). something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478711/convert-lambdaexpression-to-string-including-values

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: Basically the given expression to be converted to string with values populated in the expression

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a string, this should be your expression:

```
Func<RecordViewModel, string> exp = rec (x) => return x.Firstname == rec.Firstname &&
         x.Surname == rec.Surname ? "ReportModel.Firstname" + x.Firstname + " " 
         + "ReportModel.Surname" + " "  rec.Surname : string.empty;
```

Then you can call the expression by passin the Model:

```
var func = exp(new RecordViewModel() { Firstname= "Peter", Surname  = "Jones" });
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot alter the predicate, all I want is, serialize the predicate with values populated

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood you correctly you was given a `Func` (called exp in your example) and you need to provide a toString method for it.

You can use something like this:

```
Func<Func<ReportModel, bool>, string> toString = func => 
{
    var vm = ((dynamic)func.Target).rec;
    var paramType = func.Method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
    var firstNameProperty = paramType.GetProperties().First(p => p.Name == nameof(vm.Firstname)).Name;
    var surnameProperty = paramType.GetProperties().First(p => p.Name == nameof(vm.Surname)).Name;
    return $"(({paramType.Name}.{firstNameProperty} == \"{vm.Firstname}\") AndAlso ({paramType.Name}.{surnameProperty} == \"{vm.Surname}\"))";
};

Console.WriteLine(toString(exp(viewModel))); 
//returns ((ReportModel.Firstname == "Peter") AndAlso (ReportModel.Surname == "Jones"))
```

In there you use a bit of reflection to get the parameters (and you **know** that there is always 1 of them) of your func to make the comparison. And you look for properties of that parameter based on name.

There is also a small trick with `dynamic` to get the `rec` value (your RecordViewModel). It can be dirty, but if it works...

And, obviously,  you also hardcode the representation of your resulting string.