# Is there a way to convert a LambdaExpression to a String

Tags: java, lambda

I want to convert a LambdaExpression like `pos -> pos.x < 5 && pos.y < 5` to a String which looks like this: `"pos.x < 5 && pos.y < 5"`

Is this possible in Java?

In C# I'm using something similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478711/convert-lambdaexpression-to-string-including-values/15480176#15480176)

Comment: Lambda expressions are compiled. You can't get it as a String. You can't turn a String into a lambda expression.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Java is compiled to a set of bytecode instructions. The exact form of all Java source code, including that of lambdas, is lost at the point of compilation. It is a one-way process; certain details are irretrievably discarded (whitespace being one example, but there are other, less trivial ones) so you cannot recreate the source code from bytecode.

Comment: irreversable is a bit strong.  there are java decompilers which can reproduce java code pretty well unless the code has been specifically obfuscated

Comment: i guess our definitions of "irreversable" are a bit different then.  you are correct, you cannot get back the _exact same code_ that you passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that java provides any comparable functionality.  You can see some exploration related to lambda values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887358/reflection-type-inference-on-java-8-lambdas/25613179).